# What is the equivalent to "I appreciate it" ?

Tags: traduction, oral

Bonjour, je suis français et me demande quel serait un bon équivalent à l'expression "appreciate" ou "I appreciate it".

Hello, I am french and wonder what would be an equivalent to the expression "appreciate" or "I appreciate it".

La situation où l'expression est utilisée est telle que suit :

An example of a situation would be as follows :

Person A : This book ? No, you can keep it. I'm sure you will love it!
Person B : Thanks man, appreciate it/I appreciate it.

D'avance merci.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should separate your question between French and English, as it is it is more difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voici quelques suggestions:

- Ça me fait plaisir
- C'est très aimable [à vous]
- C'est très gentil

Note: on entend parfois *j'apprécie* mais c'est considéré comme un anglicisme :

[OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=537):

> Le verbe apprécier est parfois employé de manière incorrecte pour exprimer un souhait, une intention ou encore un sentiment de gratitude ou de reconnaissance. Ces emplois sont empruntés à la forme anglaise *to appreciate*. Pour exprimer un souhait ou une intention, on peut choisir parmi plusieurs autres verbes, par exemple souhaiter, aimer ou désirer. Pour exprimer la gratitude ou la reconnaissance, on pourra employer, entre autres, les locutions savoir gré ou être reconnaissant.

Comment: Donc j'en déduis qu'il n'existe pas de traduction reprenant précisément le sens de l'expression.

Merci pour l'info concernant l'anglicisme donc je ne me doutais pas mais qui semble être à mon sens, avec "c'est très aimable à vous", ou "c'est bien aimable" dans un contexte plus informel, la traduction la plus proche.

Answer (score 2):

As the tone of the conversation seems to be informal, that could simply be

> J'apprécie

The verb normally needs a complement (apprécier quelque chose), but it is usual to say simply that, and the meaning of the complement is implicit.

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/appr%C3%A9cier):

> Porter un jugement de valeur sur une personne ou une chose; déterminer l'importance d'un fait, d'un événement. Apprécier l'importance de...

or [Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/appr%C3%A9cier):

> 4. Par ext. Reconnaître de la valeur à une personne ou à une chose

Comment: I can't quite figure out if "j'apprécie" would be expected in this case, in french.

It feels like "I appreciate it (the gesture)" has a different, untranslatable meaning in itself. But your explanation comes close I believe.